# How to integrate a sql connection lib properly in NestJS

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, node-mssql

I'm wondering if there's a good pratice in order to use the library "mssql" in NestJS, whether if I should make a new module (and how, I'm pretty new to NestJS) or something else to implement singleton pattern for example.

I also noticed that the library comes with an audit vulnerability from axios package. Should I worry about this ?

Thanks for you help,

Answer (score 0):

I would make it a custom provider and add it and export it as a part of a module. Something like this:

```js
// mssql.constants.ts
export const MSSQL_TOKEN = Symbol('mssql');

// mssql.module.ts
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MSSQL_TOKEN,
      useFactory: async () => await mssql.connect(connectionString),
    }
  ],
  exports: [MSSQL_TOKEN],
})
export class MssqlModule {}
```

And now you can add the `MssqlModule` to the `imports` of whatever module that has a service that needs to use the `mssql` connection and in that service use `@Inject(MSSQL_TOKEN)` in the constructor, and then you're good to go. You can get fancier with a [dynamic module](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules), but this should be a good start.